# LinearLayout weight

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a probem with linearLayout weight.
I have set weightSum to be 3.
As I have 3 buttons that I want them to be equal size, every one of them has weight set to 1.
But the buttons are resizing when I click on them, even when I interact with other elements in other layours they are sometimes changing the size.
Is there any way to fix the size so the buttons are taking 100% space divided on 3 and are not resizing at all?
Thanks for help

Comment: Could you post your layout xml here?

Comment: @Neha both of above already said that

Comment: @PratikButani though the code has not been posted yet. that's why asked again to post code.

Comment: @Neha If user do not post understandable question then will get down vote, we do not have to waste time. that is problem of user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that you set the width of your buttons to 0dp and layout_weight to 1 to each button and width of linear layout should be fill parent with weight sum 3. Please paste your xml file if you still face the problem.

For Ex consider the code below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/llBtnOuter"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Button 1"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Button 1"
            android:layout_weight="1"  />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Button 1"
            android:layout_weight="1"  />
    </LinearLayout>
```

and you will get something like this

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer width 0 dp solved my problem

Comment: @user2141889 Post some code always to get quick answer

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are doing the same thing or not

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" 
        android:layout_weight = "1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button"

        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be more helpful if you post your code too.

If you want the buttons to be of equal size why don't you just use weight=1 with 0dp width or height(for each button), instead of weightSum with container layout.
That would be a solution for "...taking 100% space divided on 3..."

Answer (score 0):

```
//use this code for three button with sum 3 ******************************
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="3" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Explain something with code.